# How to check if an Android device supports eSIM?

Tags: esim

I'm using Asus Zenfone Max Pro M2. I found there's **Mobile Plan** in **Network & Internet** settings. But I'm not sure it is for eSIM.

When I tap on it, it says: *"Network has no known provisioning website"*

How to check if an Android device supports eSIM?

Answer (score 1):

Having gone through it myself,  a few weeks ago, you actually need to ask your provider if they support **esim** on that phone.

- If the esim is for the phone, then the options will become enabled and visible if you are connected to a provider that supports esim on that phone.  They may also only become available after you have purchased that option from your provider.
- If the esim is for the watch, then those options only become available after you have paired a compatible watch to your phone.  Prior to that they are either disabled or not visible.

The options may have different names on different phones.

Answer (score 0):

To post [Rahul's comment](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/214100/how-to-check-if-device-support-esim#comment274157_214100) as an answer:

> eSim depends upon carrier and mobile manufacturer. Top end devices like Pixel, Apple, nuu and top  smart watches support esim. In India Airtel and reliance jio support esim. I think Asus doesn't have such feature even if it is pure android from Google.

To see if it supports that, check manufacturer specifications. If those aren't available in detail, [GSMArena.com](https://gsmarena.com) is a great resource.

Comment: Website you mentioned doesn't provide true information.

Comment: @Swapnil it's not 100% accurate no. That's why I suggested before you check there, check with your manufacturer

Comment: Yeah thanks I will ask to the customer care